# Given 2 analytic functions $ f(x) $ and $ g(x) $

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

let be 2 analytic function so in the real line for every real number 'x' then

$$ f(x)=g(x) $$

then can we assure that for every 'z' complex number can we also have

$$ f(z)=g(z) $$

so if 2 functions are equal for are the real numbers then they are also equal for every complex number, if they ara analytic whitout poles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

True because of the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) (obviously, the set $\Bbb R$ has a cluster point in $\Bbb C$).

Comment: canb we relax the conditions a bit more ? i mean if the 2 functions are only equal on a closed interval $ (a,b) $  so on (a,b) $ f(x)=g(x)$

Comment: @JoseGarcia yes, that's correct.